# URW GOTHIC greek support

Tags: fonts

Is there a greek language support for URW Gothic with `pdflatex`? If not is there a way to use URW Gothic or any of the `TeX Gyre family` font in greek language with `pdflatex`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can substitute the font for Greek with NeoHellenic, which is a sans serif font as well. There is no available Greek version of Avant Garde/URW Gothic.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

\usepackage{avant} % uses URW Gothic
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{LGR}{\sfdefault}{neohellenic}

\begin{document}

This is English text in Avant Garde (actually URW Gothic)
and then there will be Greek text in NeoHellenic.

\begin{otherlanguage*}{greek}
Ἡ ταχεία καὶ εὐρεία ἔκθεση τοῦ κοινοῦ στὴ νέα αὐτὴ ἐπικοινωνιακὴ 
γλώσσα δὲν ἄφησε ἀνεπηρέαστο τὸν ρόλο τῆς τυπογραφίας σὲ σχέση 
μὲ τὴ λογοτεχνικὴ καὶ τὴν εἰκαστικὴ παραγωγὴ τῆς περιόδου.
\end{otherlanguage*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

URW Gothic https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/urwgothic/ or Avant Garde,

```
\usepackage{avant}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

it does not support greek letters. I suggest this compromise solution using Avant Gard (fontfamily `pag`),

```
\usepackage[euler]{textgreek} %%%% for greek letters
\usepackage{eulervm}%%%%%%%%%% for math-mode with the same style of the greek letters
```

using the engine `pdfLaTeX`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\sffamily}{pag}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sffamily}
\usepackage[euler]{textgreek}
\usepackage{eulervm}

\begin{document}
Avant gard with greek, \textbf{bold} \textit{letter} \textalpha, \textbeta \[\sum^{n}_{i=1}{n} f_i(x)\]
\end{document}
```

[image]